# Symfony 3 - Should I create two different controllers for REST and normal HTML?

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle

Symfony 3 - Should I create two different controllers for REST and normal HTML?

I already have a web application where I am using Symfony controller and twig html templates. So I already have the business logic written to fetch the content. Now I want to expose REST API to share this content with third party. Should I write a separate controller using fosrestbundle ? Or can I use  the same controller for both json and HTML? If yes, how?

Comment: You can re-use your forms if it's appropriate (similar enough), see e.g. [this tutorial](https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/symfony-rest/form-post) as a starting point.

Comment: Controllers can have multiple actions, one can return JSON, other can return `text/html`. Fosrest doesn't care.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a highly subjective question and each programmer will have another opinion to this.

I'll try to give you an answer ...

Is the REST Data requested by the page which gets already handled by the controller it might be a better choice to add just a simple json returning function for simplicity. 
Are the requirements bigger and for example a third party application may have access to this, you should go with a dedicated REST API, since there may be complete different requirements for security, response times and so on.
At the one hand, a simple Controller can't give you that features and on the other hand it's much cleaner to follow the single responsibility principle with an extra API.
But consider also creating an extra API takes also more time.

So now you should decide yourself for now and for future whether you need an dedicated API or not. The need of third party access sounds to me to go for an extra API.